# Parallel Model Training Causing Error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, time-series, forecasting

In Attempt2 below I'm trying to parallelize training two models, but I'm getting the error shown below.  It's not clear to me why the results should be any different than what I got in Attempt1, that is testArrivalCast should be the same as TaylorFcast <- forecast(Taylor2, h=80).

```
Code:

##Attempt 1 

Taylor2 <- tbats(tsdat1);
TaylorFcast <- forecast(Taylor2, h=80);

Taylor3 <- tbats(tsdat2);
Taylor3Fcast <- forecast(Taylor3, h=80);


##Attempt 2

library(parallel)
library(forecast)

# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- 2

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

tbatsList<-list(tsdat1,tsdat2)

tbatsModels<-parLapply(cl, tbatsList,
        tbats)  

stopCluster(cl)

testArrivalCast<-forecast(tbatsModels[1],h=80)


Error in x - fits : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA


Data:

dput(tsdat1)
c(0.767202484266145, 2.96949977928183, 2.0671481782824, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301, 0, 4.45424966892274, 2.75619757104319, 1.83011118413722, 
1.01872427624301, 1.53440496853229, 1.48474988964091, 0, 1.83011118413722, 
2.03744855248601, 0, 1.48474988964091, 0.689049392760799, 1.83011118413722, 
0, 3.06880993706458, 0, 1.3780987855216, 1.83011118413722, 0, 
0.767202484266145, 4.45424966892274, 0.689049392760799, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301, 3.06880993706458, 1.48474988964091, 1.3780987855216, 
0, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 
16.471000657235, 1.01872427624301, 3.06880993706458, 10.3932492274864, 
6.89049392760799, 3.66022236827445, 3.05617282872902, 0.767202484266145, 
4.45424966892274, 4.82334574932559, 7.32044473654889, 5.09362138121504, 
0.767202484266145, 10.3932492274864, 3.44524696380399, 9.15055592068612, 
7.13106993370105, 3.06880993706458, 10.3932492274864, 1.3780987855216, 
3.66022236827445, 7.13106993370105, 1.53440496853229, 5.93899955856366, 
4.13429635656479, 9.15055592068612, 6.11234565745804, 0.767202484266145, 
4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 3.66022236827445, 5.09362138121504, 
3.83601242133072, 4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 7.32044473654889, 
7.13106993370105, 4.60321490559687, 7.42374944820457, 6.20144453484719, 
7.32044473654889, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 5.93899955856366, 
2.75619757104319, 5.49033355241167, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 
5.93899955856366, 1.3780987855216, 1.83011118413722, 5.09362138121504, 
1.53440496853229, 2.96949977928183, 2.0671481782824, 7.32044473654889, 
3.05617282872902, 2.30160745279843, 8.90849933784549, 0, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301)


dput(tsdat2)
c(0, 0.677941131252747, 3.99398258840342, 15.5297069982532, 16.1737777858183, 
12.8178898504978, 6.10147018127472, 14.6446028241459, 38.824267495633, 
32.3475555716366, 24.1277926597606, 12.2029403625494, 22.6325680009527, 
41.4125519953419, 34.3692777948639, 23.373799139143, 9.49117583753845, 
15.9759303536137, 31.0594139965064, 25.2715277903411, 19.6038315360555, 
10.1691169687912, 22.6325680009527, 38.824267495633, 31.336694460023, 
24.1277926597606, 10.1691169687912, 23.9638955304205, 46.5891209947596, 
34.3692777948639, 25.6357797009956, 14.2367637563077, 27.9578781188239, 
55.6481167437407, 44.4778889110003, 36.1916889896408, 15.5926460188132, 
29.2892056482917, 59.530543493304, 62.6733889200459, 42.223637154581, 
19.6602928063297, 45.2651360019054, 106.119664488064, 78.8471667058642, 
60.3194816494014, 25.7617629876044, 51.9217736492444, 111.296233487481, 
95.0209444916825, 75.3993520617518, 34.5749976938901, 71.8916865912615, 
150.120500983114, 119.28161117041, 95.0031835978072, 42.0323501376703, 
89.198944474343, 176.003345980203, 133.433666733001, 107.067079927687, 
44.7441146626813, 90.5302720038108, 188.944768478747, 149.607444518819, 
117.622989216333, 52.2014671064615, 103.843547298489, 199.297906477583, 
151.629166742047, 113.099028092628, 50.845584843956, 102.512219769021, 
186.356483979039, 147.585722295592, 114.607015133863, 52.8794082377142, 
106.506202357424, 225.180751474671, 173.868111197547, 129.686885546213, 
56.269113893978, 109.16885741636, 209.651044476418, 161.737777858183, 
120.638963298803, 50.845584843956, 95.855582121682, 183.76819947933, 
137.477111179456, 99.5271447215123, 43.3882324001758, 78.5483242386005, 
150.120500983114, 117.259888947183, 84.447274309162, 36.6088210876483, 
68.563367767592, 126.825940485735, 95.0209444916825)
```

Comment: try wit `tbatsModels[[1]]`

Comment: @HubertL  Thank you that did the trick!